# Do I need more memory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory-usage, low-memory

I am running a website from an AWS EC2 instance (potentially multiple via Elastic Beanstalk) which over the last 24 hours shows memory percentage used consistently at 60 percent baseline, climbing to 68% sometimes.

Is this too high and should I be increasing the memory?

I ask because PageSpeed Insights tells me server response time is slow and I am wondering if memory could be part of the issue.

Comment: Slowness not always mean memory, check cpu, threads, io, interrupts etc.

Comment: How to I check these other elements (I know CPU is ok)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this too high and should I be increasing the memory?

No, and no - not if you have 30%+ memory free.